# Django scientific notation input validation

Tags: python, django

I have the following fields on my model:

```
class Range(models.Model):
    optimal_low = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=8)
    optimal_high = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=8)
```

And here's how I bring them into the form (because the form's primary object is not this model, I just need the fields, and don't want to duplicate the max_digits and decimal_places.

```
class ReadingMappingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    optimal_low = Range._meta.get_field('optimal_low').formfield()
    optimal_high = Range._meta.get_field('optimal_high').formfield()
```

It seems django allows entering of decimals in scientific notation out of the box, but there's a glitch above a certain threshold.

In the form, if I input **1.5E9** it works fine, and the value gets saved as **1500000000.00000000** (Here's an [online scientific notation calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/scientific-notation-converter.php)).

However if I input **1.5E10** it says:

> Ensure that there are no more than 8 decimal places.

Which is wrong, because I'm not adding any decimal places. In fact, if I enter **1.5E10** in normal notation, even with the 8 decimal places added, i.e. **15000000000.00000000** it works fine.

So I think something is not working correctly under the hood...

**EDIT**

I tested the field in the console, and it errors there:

```
from django.forms import DecimalField
>>> f = DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=8)
>>> f.clean('1.5E9')
Decimal('1.5E+9')
>>> f.clean('1.5E10')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "myproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "myproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 168, in clean
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "myproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 157, in run_validators
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['Ensure that there are no more than 8 decimal places.']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to be bug in DecimalValidator with the following explanation

Number that you stated **1.5E10** is parsed as object with properties `_int '15'` and `_exp 9`

In DecimalValidator `__call__` method number of decimals is calculated as

```
decimals = abs(exponent)
```

which than furthermore triggers the following

```
if self.decimal_places is not None and decimals > self.decimal_places:
    raise ValidationError(
        self.messages['max_decimal_places'],
        code='max_decimal_places',
        params={'max': self.decimal_places},
    )
```

Seems that fix for following would be something like

```
if exponent < 0:
     decimal = abs(exponent)
else:
     decimal = 0
```

Fix for version 2.0 looks like following

> ```
> # If the absolute value of the negative exponent is larger than the
> # number of digits, then it's the same as the number of digits,
> # because it'll consume all of the digits in digit_tuple and then
> # add abs(exponent) - len(digit_tuple) leading zeros after the
> # decimal point.
> if abs(exponent) > len(digit_tuple):
>     digits = decimals = abs(exponent)
> else:
>     digits = len(digit_tuple)
>     decimals = abs(exponent)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, see my reply also, this bug is fixed, but seems only for Django 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28562) which is fixed, but only in django 2.0 as far as I can tell.

Comment: I found all that too. I was gonna accept my own answer because it's technically correct, but you put more work into yours so you get the pointzzz :-)